How to prove the following equation (which involves binomials and determinant of 2×2 matrices)?
I have tried many ways to prove the following equation, such as the method of induction and expanding all the terms in the summation,but things got more complicated.I could not find an appropriate solution. I would be very happy if you come up with an ending solution I don't think i can improve my progress.
How can the following equation be proved? Or what computer software can be used to directly verify whether this equation holds?
\begin{align*}
&\binom{2n-2}{n-3}\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}\sum^{n-j-2}_{\ell=0}\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{\ell}-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\sum^{n-3}_{j=0}\sum^{n-j-4}_{\ell=0}\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{\ell} \\
&=2\sum^{n-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{\ell-1} & \binom{n-1}{j-1} \\
\binom{n-1}{\ell} & \binom{n-1}{j}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{\ell} & \binom{n-1}{\ell+1} \\
\binom{n-1}{k} & \binom{n-1}{k+1}
\end{vmatrix}
+\sum^{n-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{k-1} & \binom{n-1}{j-1} \\
\binom{n-1}{k} & \binom{n-1}{j}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{\ell} & \binom{n-1}{\ell+1} \\
\binom{n-1}{k} & \binom{n-1}{k+1}
\end{vmatrix}\\
&+2\sum^{n-1}_{m=3}\sum^{m-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{\ell-1} & \binom{n-1}{j-1} \\
\binom{n-1}{\ell} & \binom{n-1}{j}
\end{vmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix}
\binom{n-1}{m} & \binom{n-1}{m+1} \\
\binom{n-1}{k} & \binom{n-1}{k+1}
\end{vmatrix}\\
\end{align*}

OEIS tells me that the first double sum simplifies to
$$\binom{2n-2}{n-3}\sum^{n-1}{j=0}\sum^{n-j-2}{\ell=0}\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{\ell}= \binom{2 n-2}{n-3} \left[2^{2n-3}- \binom{2 n-3}{n-1}\right].$$
No luck yet with the second double sum.

Thank you very much. The double sum can have multiple expressions. I don't know which expression can be used to prove the equation I need. Incidentally, it should be added that n is required to be greater than or  equal to 4 here.

I don't know how much it helps, but on the right hand side the first sum can be removed entirely if the limit of $\ell$ in the final sum is increased to $m$ instead of $m-1$.

The left hand side appears to satisfy the D-finite recurrence $${(n-3)(n-1)n(n+1) a(n)} = {4n(2n-1)(4n^2-17n+16) a(n-1)} -{32(n-2)(2n-5)(2n-3)(2n-1) a(n-2)}$$ The second double sum (without the binomial weight) appears to have a D-finite recurrence with quadratic coefficients, which would explain why @CarloBeenakker didn't find a closed form.

@PeterTaylor Perhaps a D-finite recurrence can be found and proven for each of the five sums individually, and then the identity follows.

Thank you, Peter Taylor and  GChromodynamics , for the help you provided in proving the equation for me.

Thank you, @PeterTaylor  and GChromodynamics, for the help you provided in proving the equation for me.
