How to prove the following equation (involving multiple binomial coefficients sum)?
I encountered the equation below, encountered a problem that has been bothering me for a long time
Does anyone have an idea how to prove it? I would be extremely grateful to you if you come up with an ending solution.
\begin{align*}
&\binom{2n-2}{n-3}\sum^{n-1}_{j=0}\sum^{n-j-2}_{\ell=0}\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{\ell}-\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\sum^{n-3}_{j=0}\sum^{n-j-4}_{\ell=0}\binom{n-1}{j}\binom{n-1}{\ell} \\
&=2n^{2}\sum^{n-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\frac{(\ell-k)(\ell-j)}{(k+1)(\ell+1)(n-j)(n-\ell)}(\binom{n-1}{\ell})^{2}\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{j}+n^{2}\sum^{n-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\\
&\frac{(k-j)(\ell-k)}{(k+1)(\ell+1)(n-k)(n-j)}\binom{n-1}{\ell}(\binom{n-1}{k})^{2}\binom{n-1}{j}+2n^{2}\sum^{n-1}_{m=3}\sum^{m-1}_{\ell=2}\sum^{\ell-1}_{k=1}\sum^{k-1}_{j=0}\\
&\frac{(\ell-j)(m-k)}{(k+1)(m+1)(n-\ell)(n-j)}\binom{n-1}{m}\binom{n-1}{\ell}\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{n-1}{j},
\end{align*}
where $n\geq 4$, and $\binom{n-1}{j}$ is binomial coefficient.

Congratulations for typing the equation without errors ! I checked numerically with Mathematica. In the covered range, $4\le n\le100$, it is true. Maybe you can invest some effort to simplify ?

The version here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482544/how-to-prove-the-following-equation-which-involves-binomials-and-determinant-of looks a lot more promising to me.

Is this not algebraically identical to the question linked by Johannes?

Thank you, @JohannesTrost , for helping me verify that the equation is correct, which has given me the confidence to prove this equation.

Thank you,  @PeterTaylor. The two equations are essentially the same, I only expanded the determinant linked by Johannes here.
